# Graphviz: Align tree roots in a forest

Tags: graphviz, dot

I defined a forest (a set of trees) in [DOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)).
I am using `dot` for layouting.

Now the problem: The trees have different depths. I would like to align the root nodes on the same level, however on default the nodes are aligned by the leaves.

[image]

Comment: The very first picture in the Graphviz documentation at http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/dotguide.pdf does what I want. Unfortunately, they only show the graph, no code/explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mixed up *actual* with *expected* in your question

```
digraph {

 // create a forest hanging from the ceiling
 node[shape=box]
 edge[dir=back]
 a->b->c
 d->e->f->g
 h->i

 // ground the forest
 ground_node[style=invis]
 subgraph {
  c;g;i
 } -> ground_node [style=invis]

}
```

Comment: No, I did not mix that up. What caused the confusion probably is that I want the arrows going towards the root, i.e. the nodes at the top of the images are the roots and the yellow ones are the leaves.

Comment: top alignment is default while *grounding* is extra code as shown in my example.